# ImageJ embedded in a website

Tags: java, applet, imagej

I have downloaded ImageJ source and compiled and run ImageJ source. 
I made the ij.jar  as signed. 
But when I am trying to embed ImageJ applet in a webpage Image window is coming as popup instead of sticking onto the browser.

Many thanks to all!

Comment: You need to post some code from the file, where you embedded the applet.

Answer (score 1):

As from the ImageJ [website examples](http://imageja.sourceforge.net/applet.html), it can be directly embedded like so:

```
<applet codebase="." code="ij.ImageJApplet.class" archive="ij.jar" width=750 height=550 security=all-permissions>
  <param name=url1 value=images/pic.jpg>
  <param name=url2 value=pix/conference.jpg>
</applet>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I did this but it does not work, the applet version of ImageJ should open in a separate "ImageJ" window, so

http://www.dstretch.com/IJapplet/ImageJApplet.html

i want ImageJ embedded in a website, so

http://imageja.sourceforge.net/applet.html

do you know the link right to download the ij.jar?

i used:

imageja.sourceforge.netij.jar

http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/signed-applet/ij.jar

but Applets are not embedded in a website

Thank you for your help